# Django Rest Framework Create REST API only for executions

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a django project in which I need to build a rest API for some executions, I don't have much concerns about models as I only need to perform executions on the base of user's inputs/calls.

Here's my scenario:

1. The Major thing is the Deployment ( An App in my project )
2. On a get request user will get a list of all it's
       deployments(objects).
3. A user will send a POST request to **/deployments** along with the complete
   object as:

   ```
   {
   "deployment_name": "dep4",
   "credentials": "cre4",
   "project_name": "pro4",
   "project_id": "004",
   "cluster_name": "clus4",
   "zone_region": "zon4",
   "services": "Single",
   "configuration": "conf4",
   "routing": "route4" }
   ```

   then I need to use this data, validate and perform some execution on the base of this data. For example, I will make deployments on a cloud platform with the help of this information by using third-party APIs.

I'm really confused by the documentation of DRF, especially about serializers.

> Update: Currently, How I'm trying to do the POST:
>   From **apiview.py**

```
class DeploymentsList(APIView):
    queryset = DeploymentOnUserModel.objects.all()

    def post(self, request):
        print(request.data)
        DeploymentOnUserModel.objects.create(
            deployment_name=request.data['deployment_name'],
            credentials=request.data['credentials'],
            project_name=request.data['project_name'],
            project_id=request.data['project_id'],
            cluster_name=request.data['cluster_name'],
            zone_region=request.data['zone_region'],
            services=request.data['services'],
            configuration=request.data['configuration'],
            routing=request.data['routing'],
        )
        return Response(request.data)
```

> So, how can I validate the incoming data/request?

Here's my Deployment Model:

```
class DeploymentOnUserModel(models.Model):
    deployment_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, )
    credentials = models.TextField(blank=False)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    project_id = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    cluster_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    zone_region = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    services = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=services)
    configuration = models.TextField()
    routing = models.TextField()

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.id and self.services == 'Multiple' and not self.routing and not self.configuration:
            raise ValidationError("You must have to provide routing for multiple services deployment.")
        super().save(**kwargs)
```

> From urls.py:

```
app_name = 'deployments'

urlpatterns = [
    path('deployments/', apiview.DeploymentsList.as_view(), name='deployment_list'),
    path('deployments/<int:pk>', apiview.DeploymentDetail.as_view(), name='deployment_detail')

]
```

Which approach and things from DRF I should use to implement my API.

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to what your query is so that we might be able to help?

Comment: Well, the question is: if you don't need DRF features and DRF actually gets in the way, why would you use DRF at all ? You don't need it to build a REST api with Django, you could just do it by hand (it's only requests and responses in the end) or use some lighter lib like toastdriven's `restless`.

Comment: Hi @brunodesthuilliers, I will need other things from drf like permissions, authentications etc.

Comment: Hi @MuhammadFahadManzoor,  to implement my own get and posts like django views, should i use APIView?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to implement DRFs [ModelSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) and [ModelViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) such that you can easily reuse the Django model you already have.

Your serializer could be like this (e.g. in `serializers.py`):

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import DeploymentOnUser


class DeploymentOnUserModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DeploymentOnUser
        fields = (deployment_name, credentials, )
```

You should add your own validation here, much like you would do with Django forms.

The viewset could be like this (e.g. in `views.py`):

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import DeploymentOnUserModel
from .serializers import DeploymentOnUserModelSerializer 


class DeploymentOnUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DeploymentOnUserModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DeploymentOnUserModelSerializer 

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """overwrite this for extra actions"""
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Depending on your situation, you might even need to overwrite `create` -- this just shows how you could do it.

The `ModelViewSet` and `ModelSerializer` remove much of the boilerplate code. However, if you haven't used DRF before, it doesn't hurt to first go through the [tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/)

Don't forget to also register the viewset in `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from rest_framework import routers

from .views import DeploymentOnUserViewSet


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('deployments', DeploymentOnUserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    # other patterns also go here
    url('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

You could then test your API by doing e.g. a POST call on `/deployments/`.

For unit testing, I mostly use this pattern:

```
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory

# Create a POST request, at the root
request = APIRequestFactory().post('/')
response = DeploymentOnUserViewSet.as_view({'post': 'create'})(request)
assert response.status_code == 200
```

Comment: Hi @martyn! So, create will call when a post request comes?

Comment: Now it returns another error as: **raise TypeError("The `actions` argument must be provided when "
TypeError: The `actions` argument must be provided when calling `.as_view()` on a ViewSet. For example `.as_view({'get': 'list'})`**

Comment: Yes, `create` should be the method linked to a post call. I did not mention this in my post, but you would also need to add a router (e.g. [DefaultRouter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter) ) to your `urls.py`, similar to how you would do this for a Django app

Comment: Now, it returns `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'`

Comment: I'm not doing any unit testing, and even I have added `{'post': 'create'}` in my `url` but still, this error occurs.